# Edge: Asp.Net MVC application no longer forwards credentials on window.open() (worked in Internet Explorer 11)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, credentials, adfs

We have a CRM 2016 on-prem installation. A custom button on an entity form opens an asp.net mvc 4.6 application (app) by using JavaScript method window.open(). With Internet Explorer 11 a login window is then displayed. After successful login the app opens as expected. Both CRM and our App use ADFS for authentication.

In our company during development, everything works as expected, with both Internet Explorer and Edge. Clients and Server are in intranet. As soon as published to the customers hosting company trouble begins. It continues working with Internet Explorer but with Edge (all versions) we receive following message when trying to open our app: "sts.domain.com refused to connect" (domain is the concrete customers domain. I replaced it for security reasons). In opposite to our dev environment we access now both CRM and App over Internet. This simply as a hint. The problem exists both for us and for our client when we want to access the hosted app.

I already played with Edge Group Policies "Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/HTTP authentication/Specifies a list of servers that Microsoft Edge can delegate user credentials to" and "Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/HTTP authentication/Configure list of allowed authentication servers", but without success.

Is there something else we can configure to get it back work without modifications of our app?

Comment: I think what is needed now is to determine the cause of the problem. Since you mentioned that there is no problem in the local development environment, but the problem occurs after publishing to the customer hosting, then I think there may be a problem in the customer environment, which causes the problem. Have you checked the customer's environment-related issues?

Comment: I recommand that you can compare Edge's setting, Edge's applied policy, or whether it works in inprivate mode.